# How to do JOIN query on column having epoch value ignoring the time part in postgres

Tags: postgresql, epoch, greenplum

I have two tables lets say tableA and tableB , both the tables have a  columnn `creation_date` having epoch value in it. I want to join these two tables on creation_date ignoring the time value in it.

Lets say if the epoch value is `1603385466134` which translates to `Thu Oct 22 2020 22:21:06`. Now the join should happen as `Thu Oct 22 2020 00:00:00`

I Tried this but not working

```
Select t.lr_transaction_id, t.unique_customer_id, t.transaction_id 
from boidcrewardz.transaction_temp t 
 join boidcrewardz.transaction_dump d 
  on  t.first_6_digit_card = d.first_6_digit_card 
 and  t.transaction_amount = d.transaction_amount 
  and date_trunc('day',t.transaction_date) = date_trunc('day',d.transaction_date)  
order by t.creation_date desc
```

Comment: Not sure I get the "ignoring the time value" part - do you mean the join should happen on `Thu Oct 22 2020 00:00:00` or what are you referring to as time?

Comment: Also your translation seem to be in a specific timezone. Which one?

Comment: @PhilippJohannis yes , I edited my post,  it shoud happen on `Thu Oct 22 2020 00:00:00` and using IST time zone

Comment: `date_trunc()` only works on `timestamp` or `date` values not with `bigint` values - at least in Postgres. What are you using? Postgres or Greenplum?

Answer (score 0):

Postgres 9 and later supports [`to_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html):

> to_timestamp ( double precision ) → timestamp with time zone
>
> Convert Unix epoch (seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00+00) to timestamp
> with time zone
>
> to_timestamp(1284352323) → 2010-09-13 04:32:03+00

Postgres 8 supports `SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + 1603385466.134 * INTERVAL '1 second'`

You just need to divide your epoch value by 1000.00 as your epoch is counting milliseconds while Postgres expects seconds.

One of the following should work:

```
select date_trunc('day',to_timestamp(1603385466134/1000.00));

SELECT date_trunc('day',TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + 1603385466134/1000.00 * INTERVAL '1 second');
```